# Detecting where mouse was clicked in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, virtual-dom

In my React app, I have a side nav bar that opens and closes by clicking an icon.

If the nav bar is open and the user clicks anywhere outside of the nav bar, I still want to close it. How do I know if the click was outside of the nav bar? The main challange I have it to make sure that the click was not on a child node of the nav bar. So, checking just the nav like so isn't enough:

```
mouseDownHandler(e) {

   var container = e.target;
   if(container !== "nav-bar") {

      // Do something...
   }
};
```

I also need to make sure that the clicked area is not a child of `nav-bar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add an event listener to the document element (e.g. in `componentDidMount` of your nav-bar's component) and remove it when your nav-bar is destroyed (e.g. in `componentWillUnmount`).

Then you'll need to introduce a ref to get a handle of your nav-bar's element.

All the event handling part is answered here: [Detect clicks outside of specific div and all of it's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249339/detect-clicks-outside-of-specific-div-and-all-of-its-children)