# How to make event.target refer to a div and all its children? (detect when mouse click is NOT on a div and it's children)

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

How can I make event.target work for not just the div given but also all it's children? The best I can come up with is to either:

1) list all children in the event.target function ie:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {

  if(event.target != div && event.target != divChild1 && event.target != divChild2 && event.target != divChild3 && event.target != divChild4 && event.target != divChild5 ... && event.target != divChildn) {

  closeWindow();

  } });
```

OR

2) put all the children in a class (which seems like an awful lot of html) and then just have event.target refer to that class i.e.:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {

      if(event.target != classWithAbout50divs) {

      closeWindow();

      } });
```

But surely there is a way that requires less code..?

And please, no jquery. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the big picture? Which problem are you trying to solve by implementing this solution?

Comment: I'm trying to make a div and its children disappear whenever I click anywhere on the screen, as long as I don't click on the actual div or its children.

Comment: Right, one way to do that is to put the div inside a window-filling transparent overlay div and simply detect clicks on the overlay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect click outside div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36695438/detect-click-outside-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need direct children you can use `element.children` to loop though the children of said div.

Otherwise `element.querySelectorAll('*');` should get you all elements inside of said element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variation of the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234979/how-to-check-in-javascript-if-one-element-is-contained-within-another) to check whether `event.target` is the div in question or any of its children.

For example:

```js
function isDescendantOrSelf(parent, child) {
     let node = child;
     while (node != null) {
         if (node == parent) {
             return true;
         }
         node = node.parentNode;
     }
     return false;
}

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    const root = document.getElementById('handle');
    
    if (! isDescendantOrSelf(root, event.target)) {
        console.log('Passed!');
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="handle">
    <div>Thou</div>
    <div>
        shall <div>not</div>
    </div>
    <div>pass</div>
<div>
```

If you have the luxury of ignoring older browsers, you can refactor `isDescendantOrSelf()` to use `Node.contains()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains), as pointed out by Adam Heath [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234979/how-to-check-in-javascript-if-one-element-is-contained-within-another#comment19673187_2234986).

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution I like. First thing's first:

```
event.target != document.getElementsByClassName("myClassName");
```

Event.target doesn't seem to work if classes are referenced. I've only managed to make it work if I reference elements by ID. That is:

```
event.target != document.getElementById("myDivId");
```

Now, if I wanted something to happen whenever I DON'T click on a div and all it's children, instead of writing:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if(event.target != myDivId) {
    doSomething();
    console.log("something is done");
  }
})
```

I've found success with this:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if(!myDivId.contains(event.target) {
    doSomething();
    console.log("something is done");
  }
})
```

For potential support issues, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43249467/11930305